# Install npm package globally with puppet

Tags: npm, gruntjs, vagrant, puppet, sudo

I'm trying to install `grunt-cli` on a vagrant box using puppet:

```
node 'default' {

...

    # Install grunt globally
    package { 'grunt-cli':
      provider => npm
    }
...
```

This results in puppet attempting to execute `npm install --global grunt-cli`

The problem is it looks like this requires sudo.

This is how I'm invoking puppet from my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "vagrant/manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "vagrant/modules"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
end
```

Is there a way to use npm with sudo via puppet?
Or should I be solving this with some other approach?

(Note: a similar error occurs trying to install phantomjs in the same way)

Comment: Puppet is typically executed with elevated permissions and the daemon typically runs as root. Is it safe to assume you are trying to execute puppet without elevated permissions?

Comment: I'm new to puppet & vagrant and trying to take over a code base from another developer. The code base is quite old as well. So perhaps. It seems to want to execute as a user called vagrant. How does one typically specify the user?

Comment: If you need sudo from within vagrant, then you use sudo with the vagrant user. The vagrant user has unlimited sudo within the instance. Without knowing your codebase, I would assume either puppet is being executed with sudo by the vagrant user, or vagrant is using the puppet provisioner during instance creation (both should work).

Comment: How does one tell puppet to use sudo?

Comment: If you are using the agent, then `sudo puppet agent -t`. If you are applying a module, then `sudo puppet apply manifest.pp`. Both would work inside the instance as the vagrant user. For puppet as a provisioner, check this: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/puppet_apply.html https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/puppet_agent.html. Those would work too.

Comment: I've added in the lines from my Vagrantfile that invoke puppet. Also, I can't see anything in those two links that would allow me to specify the user, or sudo.

Comment: Oh that should be working. This is really more of a vagrant question than anything. You may want to remove a couple node.js related tags and add vagrant for better help.

Comment: Good idea, I've updated the tags. I've found that using Puppet ~v2 has fixed this issue. I'm starting to wonder how useful this question is to others. Its a bit of an edge case.